# JAVA parsing int to char

Tags: java, parsing

How can I parse int to char in java ? Here is an example of an expected outcome.

Example:

Input: 5
Output: '5'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number has one digit:

```
char c = Integer.toString(5).charAt(0);
```

If the number has more than one digit, you need a `String`:

```
String s = Integer.toString(56);
```

Answer (score 0):

48 is ASCII value of zero.

```
char ch=48+5;

System.out.println(ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char mychar = (char)(((int)'0')+i);
```